# ng-controller works, but controller in $state doesn't

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a problem with the `$elementProvider` not being found if I try to define a controller on the `$state`, for example:

```
.state('tournament', {
   url: '/tournament',
   controller: 'TournamentController',
   templateUrl: '/views/tournaments/index.html'
})
```

But it works fine if I do it in the template:

```
<div class="ui form segment" ng-controller="TournamentController">
```

Any ideas how to make it work with $state?

Comment: Can you add a little more context?  Maybe show the TournamentController definition

Comment: What error message are you getting in console?

Answer (score 0):

here is a working declaration of state routes:

```
    var ConfEditorApp = angular.module('ConfEditorApp', ['ngAnimate', 'ui.router']);

ConfEditorApp.run(['$rootScope', '$state', '$stateParams',
function ($rootScope, $state, $stateParams) {
    $rootScope.$state = $state;
    $rootScope.$stateParams = $stateParams;
}]);

ConfEditorApp.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$locationProvider',
    function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("Index")
        $stateProvider
.state('Databases', {
            url: '/Databases',
            templateUrl: 'Partials/Databases.html',
            controller: 'DatabasesSectionCtrl as databasesSection'
            });
    }]);
```

and here is the controller declaration:

```
ConfEditorApp.controller('DatabasesSectionCtrl', ['$state', '$stateParams', '$location', '$scope', '$http', '$window',
  function ($state, $stateParams, $location, $scope, $http, $window) {
......
```

try to check if something is wrong in your code or provide more info so we can checkout